# Why would a built-in Wordpress function be undefined in a plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm troubleshooting a custom plugin from one of my predecessors.

The plugin is on a Multisite installation and it creates some default posts and pages when a new site is added.

It uses the built-in WP function `get_page_by_title()` and I just got
`PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_page_by_title()`

The code in question is

```
function addPostOverview() {
    $title = 'Project Overview';
    $page = get_page_by_title($title, null, 'post');

    if (!empty($page)) {
        return;
    }

$post = array(
        'post_content' => 'Overview Example. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum mauris lorem, tempor a erat a, vehicula ultricies diam. Suspendisse in leo aliquet, ornare sapien vitae, commodo mi. Nullam ornare, mi et volutpat accumsan, enim tellus aliquam quam, vitae molestie sapien magna quis est. Praesent et magna efficitur, ornare nunc eget, commodo nunc. Donec et erat ac urna pharetra luctus et sed mauris.', // The full text of the post.
        'post_name' => 'project-overview', // The name (slug) for your post
        'post_title' => $title, // The title of your post.
        'post_status' => 'publish', //[ 'draft' | 'publish' | 'pending'| 'future' | 'private' | custom registered status ] // Default 'draft'.
        'post_type' => 'post', // [ 'post' | 'page' | 'link' | 'nav_menu_item' | custom post type ] // Default 'post'.
        'comment_status' => 'closed', // Default is the option 'default_comment_status', or 'closed'.
        'post_category' => array(get_cat_ID('Project Page'))  // Default empty.
    );

    $postID = wp_insert_post($post, $wp_error);
}
addPostOverview();
```

In what circumstances would a built-in WP function be undefined? I'm in WP 6.1.1 (latest) and just updated to PHP 8.1.

Comment: Can you give us more context please : where is this function located? in witch situation is it used?

Comment: Sure @Dexter0015 - thanks: I've updated with some more context. I don't really know what info is useful, as I don't understand why a wp function would ever be undefined...

Comment: Ok sorry I wasn't specific enough. Usually, a plugin registrer the use of its functions on Wordpress' hooks/filters. Here it seems that you execute your function completely out of the context of wordpress.

Comment: Looks like the code is running too early before the function is available... where is this code inserted?, normally an action hook should be calling it